# SAP HANA Javascript deployment

Tags: hana, xsjs

Is it possible to program extensions using Javascript only and integrate with SAP HANA system later?

Can I use API to get information from the DB, manipulate them and possibly save them to DB or external DB which will be accessed later as well?

Thank you and I am sorry but I could not find it on SAP pages.

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question? I think I can help u on this

Comment: lets assume I have js node application can I easily integrate it into HANA? and could I update DB from my app using HANA api? could I also use MONGO DB or it is supporting only SQL DBs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this is exactly what [XSJS](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_XS_JavaScript_API_Reference_en/) Can do for you. Proven and tested.
Another option would be oData which is more convenient way in case you do not need some advanced logic.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean there are two possible answers:

If you want to access the HANA SQL interface from a node.js application you can simply achieve this by using the node-hdb module from https://github.com/SAP/node-hdb.

If you want to integrate some Javascript code with SAP HANA XS applications that run server-side you'll need to get familiar with the documentation at the [SAP HANA developer guide](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/90/878018cccd40f7a4b6754c04e2d34a/content.htm?frameset=/en/90/878018cccd40f7a4b6754c04e2d34a/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/34/29fc63a1de4cd6876ea211dc86ee54/plain.htm&node_id=290&show_children=true#jump290). TL;DR yes it's possible to integrate your Javascript code with SAP HANA XS Javascript code but you have to follow some rules and it's different then in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to insert data into hana DB using Node.js
Else you can establish a JDBC connection to HANA DB and you can insert data and manipulate data.
**
Please go through this for more information

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/ff/15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4/content.htm

Note: HANA is a relational database

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node.js and HANA plugin to manipulate information like an API.

OR

You can use oData to use CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is possible to insert data into hana DB using Node.js. Now node js 6.x version is fully compatible. http://www.suryahanaacademy.com sap hana